# How can I add a photo to a contact?

Tags: contacts, photos

It seems like this should be possible - how can I add a profile photo to a contact that I manually created? At the moment they're all boring silhouettes.

In my Contacts, the only ones with photos are ones from Google or Facebook, and I can't find any option to add a photo for a contact.

I keep my contacts on the SIM, but when I copied one to the phone to see if that made a difference, it didn't, at least as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the stock People app (i.e. navigate to your contact list) > select the contact > select Edit contact > select the camera icon in the top left corner. Your options are Gallery (find an image already on your phone) or Camera (take a picture of the contact). Hope it helps!

Comment: On my Galaxy S Vibrant, the options are called _Album_ and _Take photo_ but the process is the same.

Comment: Looks like keeping contacts on my SIM was the problem :(

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to gary's method is to use "Set as".

You can open the Gallery app, select a photo and then pick Menu > More > Set as > Contact Icon. You can then choose the contact to apply it to.

The "Set as" option is sometimes available from other applications (I have a Media Gallery app on my xt720 that has it).

Answer (score 3):

The method really relies on what handset are you using. And keeping your contacts on the SIM card is one main reason for not being able to add photos to your contacts.
Anyways, navigating to any contact of your contacts and editing it then clicking on the silhouet will do the trick.